# How would cv2 access videos in AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I can use the SageMaker notebook now. But here is a significant problem. When I wanted to use cv2.VideoCapture to read the video in the s3 bucket. It said the path doesn't exist. One answer in Stackoverflow said cv2 only supports local files, which means we have to download videos from s3 bucket to notebook but I don't want to do this. I wonder how you read the videos? Thanks.

[image]

I found one solution is to use CloudFront but would this be charged and is it fast?

Comment: Will the command accept a URL to a website as the input? If so, then you could use CloudFront but it would be simpler to just use S3 by accessing the content through a URL (`http://`) rather than an S3 URI (`s3://`). This would either require the data to be publicly accessible, or to calculate special URLs to obtain access. Quite frankly, you are still better-off downloading the content locally, since the content will need to be downloaded to the computer anyway!

Comment: download to local SageMaker disk is working.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by the comment. Are you saying that you are happy to use downloads, so your question can be closed? Or are you saying that the `VideoCapture()` command works if you provide a URL?

Comment: I also posted this question on Kaggle and one answer suggests to download the data to local SageMaker disk. I tried to copy one video from s3 bucket to local disk by `aws s3 cp {s3 path} {local path}`. This way, I can use `VideoCapture()` to read. The URL doesn't work however and CloudFront is not working. I am struggling now how to download whole data to local disk. I tried `wget` but it doesn't work, don't know why. So I keep this question open for the solution is not complete yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Python in SageMaker, so you could use:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.download_file('deepfake2020', 'dfdc_train_part_1/foo.mp4', foo.mp4')
```

This will download the file from Amazon S3 to the local disk, in a file called `foo.mp4`.

See: [`download_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) in boto3

This requires that the SageMaker instance has been granted permissions to access the Amazon S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This solution is also working.

To use AWS SageMaker,

1) go to Support Center to ask to improve notebook instance limit. They will reply in 1 day normally.

2) When creating a notebook, change local disk size to 1TB (double data size).

3) Open `Jupyter lab` and type `cd SageMaker` on terminal

4) Use CurlWget to get the download link of the dataset.

5) After downloading, unzip data

`unzip dfdc_train_all.zip`

`unzip '*.zip'`

There you go.